# Can I send and receive data between workers while on a parfor (MATLAB)?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, mpi, parallel.for

I would like to know if I could trade (send and receive) data between nodes while executing a parfor. What I would like to accomplish is something like this:

```
parfor i = 1:4

    %Perform a computation on each column of a 4x4 matrix on 4 different workers (each worker takes one column).

    %Make Worker #1 send its data to Worker #3, Worker #3 to Worker #1, Worker #2 ro Worker #4 and Worker #4 to Worker #2.

    %Make other computations on the data received from the other workers

end
```

I would like to perform all these computations without leaving the parfor. Are there any MPI commands I can use for this? Is this achievable? If so, how could I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this within `parfor`, where the iterations must be independent. Instead, take a look at the `spmd` block, and the commands `labSend`, `labReceive` and `labBroadcast`.

Comment: Awesome! So could I do something like this?:

`spmd
    for i = 1:4
        if(labindex == i)
            %Instructions mentioned on original post
        end
    end
end`

Comment: I found out how to do it: `spmd(4) %Instructions mentioned before end` I also used `labSend` and `labReceive` Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Data cannot be exchanged between `parfor` instances. That's part of the use of `parfor`, to have individual tasks, that are truly independent. There is no guarentee how many of them will be running at the same time, for instance. On some computers, `parfor` will only allow 1 instance, on others it may allow 4 running at the same time, still others only 2 at a time.

Matlab as a whole doesn't do threading really, but it does have a few constructs that allow for thread-like applications. In general, however, they are quite complex, and not really useful.